# UUID of Alert Notification Profile - ANP (in GATT), in Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am working with `Alert Notification Profile (ANP) in Bluetooth Low Energy` between Samsung Galaxy S3 and peripheral device.

I can not find any information related to **specific UUID's ANP** at [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).

But in `ANCS Specifications` [(iOS Developer Site)](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW7), They define **specific UUID's ANCS** :

> The Apple Notification Center Service is a primary service whose service UUID is 7905F431-B5CE-4E99-A40F-4B1E122D00D0.

I feel worry about this different, so anyone can tell me about :

`What is specific UUID's ANP in Android?`

*P/s : From UUID in Wiki, I know this :*

> Anyone can create a UUID and use it to identify something with reasonable confidence that the same identifier will never be unintentionally created by anyone to identify something else.

*But actually, Google Developer has not confirmed about specific UUID's ANP yet?*

Comment: Check bluetooth sig link in which UUID' are defined [bluetooth SIG](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx)

Comment: I also check ANS - Alert Notification Service, at Bluetooth site, but I only found `Assigned Number: 0x1811`, can not find out UUID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic Bluetooth is : 0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb.

"xxxx" is `Assigned Number` you need replace in it, you can declared.

But the other thing, at firmware side also define that UUID for Mobile Application can communicate with Firmware.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to know the uuid of profile. You need to know the uuids of services belong to this profile. It has one services and the uuid is 00001811-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Also yoou need to know the uuids characteristics belong to this services to get the value of them. It has 5 characteristics:

1- New Alert Category               :  00002A47-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
2- New Alert                        :  00002A46-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
3- Supported Unread Alert Category  :  00002A48-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

etc..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use the Phone to send Alert to an external device ?

If I understand correctly the bluetooth specs, https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/ANS.aspx , your Phone is supposed to be turned into a peripheral, not a central to do that.

Peripheral = slave, server
central = master, client

The issue is, android phones can't be turned into peripherals (so far) https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59693

While it is probable that a future update fixes this, it is not an available feature yet.

Of course you could always hack your way into making it available ;-) but that'd be a dirty solution http://blog.cozybit.com/enabling-peripheral-mode-in-android-kitkat-4-4/